# Mocha REST API request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am writing the test framework to test my server written in node.js.

---

Sample Test Case:

- call API "GET /authenticate" and store "Token"

  Example: curl -k -X GET https://.org:8000/vxapi/1.0/authenticate -H "username:root" -H "password:root123"

  {"Token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhOWRmZDI5ZjE3YzQiLCJpYXQiOjE0ODcwNzgwMTB9.Nitd5DnWTCbSw8enXVaGdGRYWuYQx7ojRaYESnsTuZY","Status":"OK"}
- Then pass "Token" as header to other requests as "GET /volume"

---

Currently, I am writing the script to atleast authenticate and generate the Token and display in response. It's throwing the error as "  GET /user
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined]". ***Just want to confirm if the header is the problem or its the issue with "https".***

---

```
var should = require("should")
var request = require("supertest");
var url = "https://.org:8000/vxapi/1.0"
describe('GET /user', function() {
 it('respond with json', function(done) {
   request(url)
  .get('/authenticate')
  .set('username', 'root')
  .set('password', 'root123')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function (err, res) {
   if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return done
   }

   console.log(res)
   done()
   })
 });
})
```

Edit: Solution is to add the line process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0" to bypass https secure check